# Given Anton's attitudes expressed to Budakh, why did Earth start Progressors?

Tags: russian-language, strugatsky-brothers, hard-to-be-a-god

In conversation with Doctor Budakh - and later Arata, Rumata (Anton) basically states the Earth's - and his personal - party line about non-interference with foreign cultures:

> — Что ж, — сказал он, — извольте. Я сказал бы всемогущему: «Создатель, я не знаю твоих планов, может быть, ты и не собираешься делать людей добрыми и счастливыми. Захоти этого! Так просто этого достигнуть! Дай людям вволю хлеба, мяса и вина, дай им кров и одежду. Пусть исчезнут голод и нужда, а вместе с тем и все, что разделяет людей».
>   ... — **Бог ответил бы вам: «Не пойдет это на пользу людям. Ибо сильные вашего мира отберут у слабых то, что я дал им, и слабые по-прежнему останутся нищими».**

*[I'm paraphrasing here, not direct-translating, for brevity - DVK]*

> It won't help the people to give them enough nourishment, housing and
>   clothes - the strong will take the goods from the weak, and the weak
>   will stay in poverty.    — Я бы попросил бога оградить слабых,
>   «Вразуми жестоких правителей», сказал бы я.   — **Жестокость есть
>   сила. Утратив жестокость, правители потеряют силу, и другие жестокие
>   заменят их**.
>
> It won't help to protect the weak by making the strong weaker, as the
>   new rulers who are harsh will arise to replace the ones you made
>   weaker.
>
> — Накажи жестоких, — твердо сказал он, — чтобы неповадно было сильным
>   проявлять жестокость к слабым.    — **Человек рождается слабым.
>   Сильным он становится, когда нет вокруг никого сильнее его. Когда
>   будут наказаны жестокие из сильных, их место займут сильные из слабых.
>   Тоже жестокие. Так придется карать всех, а я не хочу этого**.
>
> It won't help to punish the harsh ones, as the ones just less weak
>   than them will arise and turn harsh, requiring to punish *everyone*.
>
> — Тебе виднее, всемогущий. Сделай тогда просто так, чтобы люди
>   получили все и не отбирали друг у друга то, что ты дал им.   — **И это
>   не пойдет людям на пользу, — вздохнул Румата, — ибо когда получат они
>   все даром, без трудов, из рук моих, то забудут труд, потеряют вкус к
>   жизни и обратятся в моих домашних животных, которых я вынужден буду
>   впредь кормить и одевать вечно**.
>
> It won't help to just give everything to everyone, as humans will just
>   turn to cattle, forever dependent on the god who gave them the
>   abundance.
>
> Не давай им всего сразу! — горячо сказал Будах. — Давай понемногу,
>   постепенно!   — **Постепенно люди и сами возьмут все, что им
>   понадобится.**
>
> There's no point in giving things bit by bit, as humans will achieve
>   that progress on their own.
>
> Будах неловко засмеялся.   — Да, я вижу, это не так просто, — сказал
>   он. — Я как-то не думал раньше о таких вещах… Кажется, мы с вами
>   перебрали все. Впрочем, — он подался вперед, — есть еще одна
>   возможность. Сделай так, чтобы больше всего люди любили труд и знание,
>   чтобы труд и знание стали единственным смыслом их жизни!   Да, это мы
>   тоже намеревались попробовать, подумал Румата. Массовая гипноиндукция,
>   позитивная реморализация. Гипноизлучатели на трех экваториальных
>   спутниках…   — Я мог бы сделать и это, — сказал он. — **Но стоит ли
>   лишать человечество его истории? Стоит ли подменять одно человечество
>   другим? Не будет ли это то же самое, что стереть это человечество с
>   лица земли и создать на его месте новое?**    Будах, сморщив лоб,
>   молчал обдумывая. Румата ждал. За окном снова тоскливо заскрипели
>   подводы. Будах тихо проговорил:
>
> And it won't do to mind-wipe everyone and turn them into Earth-model
>   communars. Since basically it's the same as killing them and replacing
>   them with earthlings.
>
> — Тогда, господи, сотри нас с лица земли и создай заново более
>   совершенными… или еще лучше, оставь нас и дай нам идти своей дорогой. 
>   — Сердце мое полно жалости, — медленно сказал Румата. — Я не могу
>   этого сделать.

TL;DR: doesn't matter what you as Earth do, the only two ways are to let people's society develop on their own and progress at their own pace; OR, replace them wholesale with a new society.

Given that set of views (not an unreasonable one), **what changed so that, a mere couple of decades later, in the same Noon universe, [Progressors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressor) - whose whole core goal is antithetical to what Anton expressed - are working everywhere in the universe** - including, as per "*Waves Extinguish the Wind*" Arkanar itself, where Toyvo Glumov worked as a Progressor.

Comment: Would you like me add translations from my book?

Comment: @Gallifreyan - I never object :)

Comment: Hmm. Then do you mind if I just replace everything, including the Russian text,  with the English version?

Comment: @Gallifreyan - your call. You know my stance on original text in posts :)

Comment: Aye. I'll add the translations when I get home.

Comment: @Gallifreyan ... 3 years later? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a fragment of [interview with Boris Strugatsky](http://www.sedenko.pl/2011/01/19/wywiad-z-borysem-strugackim-2002/) (in Polish)

The relevant fragment:

> Our shallow look at the progressors and their ideas have been replaced with something deeper [...].Humanity, after reaching the level have to become progressors becauses **there always will be people who can't live happy knowing that somewhere blood is being spilled and children are hurt, especially if they have resources to change it**

As a side note, there is a short story "Its NOT hard to be a God" written by Marek Oramus that shows the bad way the progressor movement can end - they came out of hiding, slowly took over power "for the greater good" and quickly turned into tyrants.